# Is there any other way to create obstacles in a snake game?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a python program for a snake game with obstacles...
I am able to create obstacles one by one like

```
import pygame
import math
import random
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirxny=0,color=(255,0,0)):
        self.pos = start
        self.dirnx = 1
        self.dirny = 0
        self.color = color

    def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
        self.dirnx = dirnx
        self.dirny = dirny
        self.pos = (self.pos[0] +self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+1, j*dis+1,dis+2,dis-2))
        if eyes:
            centre = dis//2
            radius = 3
            circleMiddle = (i*dis + centre-radius,j*dis+8)
            circleMiddle2 = (i*dis + dis -radius*2, j*dis + 8)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface,(255,255,255), circleMiddle, radius)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface,(255,255,255), circleMiddle2, radius)

class snake(object):
    body = []
    turns = {}
    def __init__(self,color,pos):
        self.color = color
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def move(self):
        for event in  pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]             
                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:                                                
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]             
                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:                                                 
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]                    

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]  

        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in self.turns:
                turn = self.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0], turn[1])       
                if i == len(self.body)-1:
                    self.turns.pop(p)          
            else:
                if c.dirnx == -1 and c.pos[0]<=0:          c.pos = (c.rows, c.pos[1])
                if c.dirnx == 1 and c.pos[0]>= c.rows - 1: c.pos = (-1, c.pos[1])
                if c.dirny == -1 and c.pos[1]<=0:          c.pos = (c.pos[0], c.rows)
                if c.dirny == 1 and c.pos[1]>=rows - 1:    c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                else:                                      c.move(c.dirnx,c.dirny)
    def reset(self,pos):
        self.head= cube(pos)
        self.body = []
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.turns = {}
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1
    def addCube(self):
        tail = self.body[-1]
        dx, dy = tail.dirnx, tail.dirny

        if dx==1 and dy==0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]-1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx==-1 and dy==0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]+1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx==0 and dy==1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]-1)))
        elif dx==0 and dy==-1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]+1)))

        self.body[-1].dirnx = dx
        self.body[-1].dirny = dy

    def draw(self,surface):
        for i,c in enumerate(self.body):
            if i ==0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))  
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))
def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width, s, snack, obs1,obs2,obs3
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    obs1.draw(surface)
    obs2.draw(surface)
    obs3.draw(surface)
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()
def randomSnack(rows, item):
    positions = item.body

    while True:
        x = random.randrange(rows)
        y = random.randrange(rows)
        if len(list(filter(lambda z:z.pos == (x,y), positions)))>0:
            continue
        else:
            break
    return (x,y)

def message_box(subject, content):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(subject,content)
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:

        pass


def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack,obs1,obs2,obs3
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,width))
    s = snake((255,255,0), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows,s),color = (0,255,0))
    flag = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50) 
        clock.tick(10)     
        obs1= cube((15,9),color = (255,100,50))
        obs2= cube((15,8),color = (255,100,50))
        obs3= cube((15,7),color = (255,100,50))
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color = (0,255,0))

        for x in (range(len(s.body))):
            if ((s.body[0].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos, s.body[x+1:]))) or s.body[0].pos in (obs1.pos,obs2.pos,obs3.pos)):
                print('Score: ', len(s.body))
                message_box('!You Lost!', 'PlayAgain...')
                s.reset((10,10))
                break

        redrawWindow(win)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                flag = False
                sys.exit()

main()
```

In the main function there is a for loop inside which there is an if statement, Is there anyway by which I can make a list of obstacles like obstacles = [obs1,obs2,obs3] and then check it in the if statement??

Comment: Original snake was implemented using [cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). In this approach adding obstacles or checking snake collisions is a trivial task, you just check if head reaches empty cell or cell containing fruit, obstacle or snake tail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can create a list such as `obstacles = [obs1,obs2,obs3]`
However, I strongly recommend using making an obstacle class. 
This way, you will be able to append the obstacle to the list using something such as `obstacles.append(obstacle(parameters))`

Comment: Thanx WangGang!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extend your current version to use a list. Change:

```
if ((s.body[0].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos, s.body[x+1:]))) or s.body[0].pos in (obs1.pos,obs2.pos,obs3.pos)):
```

To:

```
if ((s.body[0].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos, s.body[x+1:]))) or s.body[0].pos in obsticals):
```

and create an obsticals list of tuples

```
obsticals = [(20, 10), (3, 39), (25, 23), ...]
```